# abscissa of convergence of $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $\sigma \geq \frac{1}{2}$.  How does one show that, if $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros for $\operatorname{Re} s > \sigma$, then the Dirichlet series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$ of the M"obius function $\mu(n)$ converges for $\operatorname{Re} s > \sigma$?  Either a proof or a reference containing the proof is fine.

Related question on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/341916/on-the-dirichlet-series-for-1-zetas-for-real-s-and-the-zeros-of-zeta

Comment: My first idea would be to look at Tenenbaum’s *Introduction to analytic and probabilistic number theory*, but I don’t know if it’s actually there.

Comment: Broughan  Equivalents of RH volume 1 has this in chapter  4 (Classical Equivalences) but the idea is simple; if $\zeta$ has no zeroes on $\Re s > \sigma$ then $\log \zeta$ is analytic and bounded by $c \log |t|$ on the vertical line $\Re s >\sigma+\epsilon$ and by $c$ on $\Re s >2$ so by the three circles theorem we get it as $o(\log t)$ in-between so $1/\zeta =o_{\delta}(t^{\delta})$ for any $\delta >0$ (in jargon, $\mu_{1/\zeta}(\sigma_1)=0, \sigma_1 \ge \sigma$); using Perron for $1/\zeta$ on $\Re s >1$ and Cauchy to move to $\Re s >\sigma$ the estimate above implies the convergence there

Comment: @Conrad The theorem in Broughan assumes the Riemann hypothesis, as do all versions of the equivalence I can find in the literature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will outline how those properties can be related to each other.  It is through an intermediate integral involving $M(x) = \sum_{1 \leq n \leq x} \mu(n)$.

For a sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $\mathbf C$, with $A(x) = \sum_{1 \leq n \leq x} a_n$ for $x > 0$, and $\sigma_0 \geq 0$, the following two conditions are equivalent:

(i) $A(x) = O_\varepsilon(x^{\sigma_0+\varepsilon})$ for all $\varepsilon>0$,

(ii) the series $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n/n^s$ converges for ${\rm Re}(s) > \sigma_0$.

When these conditions hold, the series is analytic on ${\rm Re}(s) > \sigma_0$ and
$$
\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{a_n}{n^s} = s\int_1^\infty \frac{A(x)}{x^{s+1}}\,dx
$$
for ${\rm Re}(s) >\sigma_0$, where $\int_1^\infty = \lim_{T \to \infty} \int_1^T$ and the integral is absolutely convergent on each half-plane $\{s : {\rm Re}(s) \geq \sigma_0+\varepsilon\}$.

We will apply this with $a_n = \mu(n)$, and set $M(x) = \sum_{1 \leq n \leq x} \mu(n)$.

For ${\rm Re}(s) > 1$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} = s\int_1^\infty \frac{M(x)}{x^{s+1}}\,dx.
$$

Open right half-planes where $\zeta(s)$ is zero-free are the same thing as open right half-planes where $1/\zeta(s)$ is analytic.

For $\sigma_0 \geq 1/2$, if $M(x) = O_\varepsilon(x^{\sigma_0 + \varepsilon})$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$ then on the half-plane ${\rm Re}(s) > \sigma_0$ the integral involving $M(x)/x^{s+1}$ is absolutely convergent, the series $\sum \mu(n)/n^s$ converges, and $1/\zeta(s) = \sum \mu(n)/n^s$ by uniqueness of analytic continuation (we already know $1/\zeta(s)$ is meromorphic on $\mathbf C$). It turns out a converse is true, but is much more technical to prove: if $\zeta(s) \not= 0$ for ${\rm Re}(s) > \sigma_0$, so $1/\zeta(s)$ is analytic on that half-plane, then $M(x) = O_\varepsilon(x^{\sigma_0 + \varepsilon})$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: Your last assertion, the more technical converse, is equivalent to what I'm asking for.  How does the proof of that work?  Is there a reference for it?  I can't find a proof of it in any of the analytic number theory books I have.

Comment: One can use the theorem of Landau that if $f$ holomorphic on $\Re s >\sigma$ is given as a Dirichlet series convergent on $\Re s >\sigma_a $ and $f(\sigma_1+it)=O_\delta(|t|^{\delta})$ for any $\delta>0, \sigma<\sigma_1$, then the Dirichlet series of $f$ converges to $f$ on $\Re s >\sigma$ plus the three circle theorem of Hadamard applied to $\log \zeta$ to show that if $\zeta$ has no zero on $\Re s >\sigma$ then $ 1/\zeta$ satisfies the requirement above

Comment: @Conrad The proof you mention in the Broughan book assumes the Riemann hypothesis.  Also, I can't find a reference to the theorem of Landau you mentioned.

Comment: for the theorem of Landau see Titchmarsh Theory of Functions 9.44 p 302; given a pseudo-RH (no zeroes for $\Re s > \sigma_0 \ge 1/2$), the way to prove that $1/\zeta$ satisfies the hypothesis in Landau's theorem (analytic and of Dirichlet series order $0$ in $\Re s > \sigma_0$ so its Dirichlet series converges there) follows in the same way Lindelof follows from RH by using the three circles theorem and the fact that $\log \zeta$ is analytic in $\Re s > \sigma_0, |t| \ge 1$, it is $O(1)$ in $\Re s \ge 2$ and it is $O(\log t)$ otherwise, so it is $o(\log t)$ in $\Re s > \sigma_0, |t| \ge 1$

Comment: note that the above implies that both $\zeta, 1/\zeta$ are $O_{\epsilon}(|t|^{\epsilon})$ in $\Re s > \sigma_0, |t| \ge 1$ on the pseudo-RH, no zeroes of $\zeta$ in $\Re s > \sigma_0$, but $1/\zeta$ is also analytic in the full half plane $\Re s > \sigma_0$ then, while $\zeta$ has a pole so the application of Landau's theorem is of course specific only to $1/\zeta$ here

Comment: @Conrad  Thank you.  I figured that the proof generalized as such.  I'm really surprised that a proof of the generalization as stated doesn't seem to be anywhere in the literature.

Comment: Most likely becaue quasi RH is as hard as RH so unlikely to be proven before